# Определенный div ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Имеется данный код, как сделать так, что бы он выполнялся всегда, а не только 1 раз во время document.ready

```
$(function() {
    $("a").on("click",function() {
        $(".content").html('<div class="content__ajax_load"></div>');
        var Content = $(this).attr("href");
        $.ajax({
            url: Content,
            success: function(data) {
                $(".content").load(Content + " .content__ajax");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: какой именно код должен выполняться **всегда**? навешивание обработчика?

Answer (score 1):

Видимо вы хотите сделать нечто подобное:

```js
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #div_container" );
```

Comment: Спасибо, обновил вопрос

Comment: @asd, а надо было перед этим подумать... Это ж не в коллбек надо писать.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, так:

```
$(data).find("div")
```

или так (предварительно проверив поддержку браузерами):

```
$((new DOMParser).parseFromString(data, 'text/html')).find("div")
```